# Как последовательно сократить список? [python]

Tags: python, python-3.x

Изучаю питон по книге Э.Мэтиза, помогите разобраться с задачей пожалуйста.

**Задача:**
Используйте метод pop() для последовательного удаления гостей из списка до тех пор, пока в списке не останется только 2 человека. Каждый раз, когда из списка удаляется очередное имя, выведи для этого человека сообщение о том, что ты сожалеешь об отмене приглашения.

**Мой код:**

```
guests = ['алина', 'давид', 'кобзон', 'алена', 'саша', 'вася']
for guest in guests:
    count_guests = len(guests)
    if count_guests != 2:
        popped_guests = guests.pop()
        print(popped_guests.title() + ', вы удалены из списка приглашенных! Мне жаль!')
    else:
        print(guest.title() + ', а для вас осталось приглашение!')
```

**Терминал выводит такой ответ:**

```
Вася, вы удалены из списка приглашенных! Мне жаль!
Саша, вы удалены из списка приглашенных! Мне жаль!
Алена, вы удалены из списка приглашенных! Мне жаль!
```

Вопросы: почему не срабатывает else? почему удаляет только 3 из 6 элементов списка, когда должен вроде удалить 4? Спасибо!

Comment: потому вы изменяете список по которому итерируетесь. после удаления "алёны" цикл `for guest in guests` завершается.

Answer (score 3):

Для таких целей лучше всего использовать цикл `while`.

```
guests = ['алина', 'давид', 'кобзон', 'алена', 'саша', 'вася']
while len(guests) > 2:
    popped_guest = guests.pop()
    print(popped_guest.title() + ', вы удалены из списка приглашенных! Мне жаль!')
```

Ну и если вы хотите вывести тех, кому приглашение досталось:

```
guests = ['алина', 'давид', 'кобзон', 'алена', 'саша', 'вася']
while len(guests) > 2:
    popped_guest = guests.pop()
    print(popped_guest.title() + ', вы удалены из списка приглашенных! Мне жаль!')
for g in guests:
    print(g.title() + ', а для вас осталось приглашение!')
```

Comment: Спасибо! Думал о while, но не додумал)) Странно, что у метиза эта задача идет вообще до описания циклов в его книге.

Comment: @kirillkorobkin в таком случае можно `while`  заменить на `for _ in range(len(guests)-2):`, чтобы не отходить от порядка изучения. но с `while` оно понятнее.

Answer (score 2):

Вы зря вот это:

```
for guest in guests:
```

затеяли. На четвёртом круге цикл должен дойти до Алёны, а её уже и нет.

Измените цикл

Comment: Спасибо. А почему на четвертом круге Алены нет?

Comment: Потому что метод pop удаляет элементы с конца списка

Answer (score 1):

Используйте цикл While, удаляя элементы, пока в списке их не останется два.

```
guests = ['алина', 'давид', 'кобзон', 'алена', 'саша', 'вася']
while len(guests) > 2:
        popped_guests = guests.pop()
        print(popped_guests.title() + ', вы удалены из списка приглашенных! Мне жаль!')
else:
    print([guest.title()+ ', а для вас осталось приглашение!' for guest in guests])
```

Comment: А зачем тут `else`? Этот блок всегда сработает, в цикле же нет `break`.

Comment: @CrazyElf Я постарался, чтобы программа была похожа на ту, что автор писал, тем более он по книге это делал. А так да, согасен, else тут не нужен